# exclude row 1 when importing CSV file to MYSQL using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have the following code that imports a CSV file into MYSQL table. The only problem is that it also import the header row. How can I alter the below code so that it doesn't include the top row.

I looked around and found 'IGNORE 1 LINES', but have yet to get it working.

Also, what does that '500' mean?

```
//connect to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// open the csv file
$fp = fopen($filename,"r");

//parse the csv file row by row
while(($row = fgetcsv($fp,"500",",")) != FALSE)
{
    //insert csv data into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table92108 (date,filename,directory,type,email) VALUES('" . implode("','",$row) . "')";
    if(!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysqli_error());
    }
}

fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Here is my second attempt based on answer below, but still doesn't work. What did I do wrong???

```
//connect to mysql database
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

// open the csv file
$fp = fopen($filename,"r");

//parse the csv file row by row
$count = 0;
while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 500, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $count++;
    if ($count == 1) { continue; }

{
    //insert csv data into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table92108 (date,filename,directory,type,email) VALUES('" . implode("','",$row) . "')";
    if(!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        die('Error : ' . mysqli_error());
    }
}

fclose($fp);

//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

Comment: 500 = length, you will find more detail from http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgetcsv.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [skip first line of fgetcsv method in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372730/skip-first-line-of-fgetcsv-method-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I used that class for import csv file.

```
**Quick_CSV_import.php**

<?php 


class Quick_CSV_import 
{ 
  var $table_name; //where to import to 
  var $file_name; //where to import from 
  var $use_csv_header; //use first line of file OR generated columns names 
  var $field_separate_char; //character to separate fields 
  var $field_enclose_char; //character to enclose fields, which contain separator char into content 
  var $field_escape_char; //char to escape special symbols 
  var $error; //error message 
  var $arr_csv_columns; //array of columns 
  var $table_exists; //flag: does table for import exist 
  var $encoding; //encoding table, used to parse the incoming file. Added in 1.5 version 

  function Quick_CSV_import($file_name="") 
  { 
    $this->file_name = $file_name; 
    $this->arr_csv_columns = array(); 
    $this->use_csv_header = true; 
    $this->field_separate_char = ","; 
    $this->field_enclose_char = "\""; 
    $this->field_escape_char = "\\"; 
    $this->table_exists = false; 
  } 

  function import() 
  { 
    if($this->table_name=="") 
      $this->table_name = "temp_".date("d_m_Y_H_i_s"); 

    $this->table_exists = false; 
    $this->create_import_table(); 

    if(empty($this->arr_csv_columns)) 
      $this->get_csv_header_fields(); 

    /* change start. Added in 1.5 version */ 
    if("" != $this->encoding && "default" != $this->encoding) 
      $this->set_encoding(); 
    /* change end */ 

    if($this->table_exists) 
    { 
      $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".@mysql_escape_string($this->file_name). 
             "' INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name. 
             "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_separate_char). 
             "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char). 
             "' ESCAPED BY '".@mysql_escape_string($this->field_escape_char). 
             "' ". 
             ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "") 
             ."(`".implode("`,`", $this->arr_csv_columns)."`)"; 
      $res = @mysql_query($sql); 
      $this->error = mysql_error(); 
    } 
  } 

  //returns array of CSV file columns 
  function get_csv_header_fields() 
  { 
    $this->arr_csv_columns = array(); 
    $fpointer = fopen($this->file_name, "r"); 
    if ($fpointer) 
    { 
      $arr = fgetcsv($fpointer, 10*1024, $this->field_separate_char); 
      if(is_array($arr) && !empty($arr)) 
      { 
        if($this->use_csv_header) 
        { 
          foreach($arr as $val) 
            if(trim($val)!="") 
              $this->arr_csv_columns[] = $val; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
          $i = 1; 
          foreach($arr as $val) 
            if(trim($val)!="") 
              $this->arr_csv_columns[] = "column".$i++; 
        } 
      } 
      unset($arr); 
      fclose($fpointer); 
    } 
    else 
      $this->error = "file cannot be opened: ".(""==$this->file_name ? "[empty]" : @mysql_escape_string($this->file_name)); 
    return $this->arr_csv_columns; 
  } 

  function create_import_table() 
  { 
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$this->table_name." ("; 

    if(empty($this->arr_csv_columns)) 
      $this->get_csv_header_fields(); 

    if(!empty($this->arr_csv_columns)) 
    { 
      $arr = array(); 
      for($i=0; $i<sizeof($this->arr_csv_columns); $i++) 
          $arr[] = "`".$this->arr_csv_columns[$i]."` TEXT"; 
      $sql .= implode(",", $arr); 
      $sql .= ")"; 
      $res = @mysql_query($sql); 
      $this->error = mysql_error(); 
      $this->table_exists = ""==mysql_error(); 
    } 
  } 

  /* change start. Added in 1.5 version */ 
  //returns recordset with all encoding tables names, supported by your database 
  function get_encodings() 
  { 
    $rez = array(); 
    $sql = "SHOW CHARACTER SET"; 
    $res = @mysql_query($sql); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) 
    { 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res)) 
      { 
        $rez[$row["Charset"]] = ("" != $row["Description"] ? $row["Description"] : $row["Charset"]); //some MySQL databases return empty Description field 
      } 
    } 
    return $rez; 
  } 

  //defines the encoding of the server to parse to file 
  function set_encoding($encoding="") 
  { 
    if("" == $encoding) 
      $encoding = $this->encoding; 
    $sql = "SET SESSION character_set_database = " . $encoding; //'character_set_database' MySQL server variable is [also] to parse file with rigth encoding 
    $res = @mysql_query($sql); 
    return mysql_error(); 
  } 
  /* change end */ 

} 

?>
```

> here is example

```
<?php 
include "Quick_CSV_import.php"; 

//connect to database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1"); 
mysql_select_db("test"); //your database 

$csv = new Quick_CSV_import(); 

$arr_encodings = $csv->get_encodings(); //take possible encodings list 
$arr_encodings["default"] = "[default database encoding]"; //set a default (when the default database encoding should be used) 

if(!isset($_POST["encoding"])) 
  $_POST["encoding"] = "default"; //set default encoding for the first page show (no POST vars) 

if(isset($_POST["Go"]) && ""!=$_POST["Go"]) //form was submitted 
{ 
  $csv->file_name = $HTTP_POST_FILES['file_source']['tmp_name']; 

  //optional parameters 
  $csv->use_csv_header = isset($_POST["use_csv_header"]); 
  $csv->field_separate_char = $_POST["field_separate_char"][0]; 
  $csv->field_enclose_char = $_POST["field_enclose_char"][0]; 
  $csv->field_escape_char = $_POST["field_escape_char"][0]; 
  $csv->encoding = $_POST["encoding"]; 

  //start import now 
  $csv->import(); 
} 
else 
  $_POST["use_csv_header"] = 1; 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> 

<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Quick CSV import</title> 
  <style> 
  .edt 
  { 
    background:#ffffff; 
    border:3px double #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-left-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-right-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-top-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-bottom-colors:#aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    width: 350px; 
  } 
  .edt_30 
  { 
    background:#ffffff; 
    border:3px double #aaaaaa; 
    font-family: Courier; 
    -moz-border-left-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-right-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-top-colors: #aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    -moz-border-bottom-colors:#aaaaaa #ffffff #aaaaaa; 
    width: 30px; 
  } 
  </style> 
</head> 

<body bgcolor="#f2f2f2"> 
  <h2 align="center">Quick CSV import</h2> 
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <table border="0" align="center"> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Source CSV file to import:</td> 
          <td rowspan="30" width="10px">&nbsp;</td> 
          <td><input type="file" name="file_source" id="file_source" class="edt" value="<?=$file_source?>"></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Use CSV header:</td> 
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="use_csv_header" id="use_csv_header" <?=(isset($_POST["use_csv_header"])?"checked":"")?>/></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Separate char:</td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="field_separate_char" id="field_separate_char" class="edt_30" maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_separate_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_separate_char"]) : ",")?>"/></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Enclose char:</td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="field_enclose_char" id="field_enclose_char" class="edt_30" maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_enclose_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_enclose_char"]) : htmlspecialchars("\""))?>"/></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Escape char:</td> 
          <td><input type="text" name="field_escape_char" id="field_escape_char" class="edt_30" maxlength="1" value="<?=(""!=$_POST["field_escape_char"] ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["field_escape_char"]) : "\\")?>"/></td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td>Encoding:</td> 
          <td> 
          <select name="encoding" id="encoding" class="edt"> 
          <? 
            if(!empty($arr_encodings)) 
              foreach($arr_encodings as $charset=>$description): 
          ?> 
<option value="<?=$charset?>"<?=($charset == $_POST["encoding"] ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")?>><?=$description?></option> 
          <? endforeach;?> 
</select> 
        </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
          <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="Submit" name="Go" value="Import it" onclick=" var s = document.getElementById('file_source'); if(null != s && '' == s.value) {alert('Define file name'); s.focus(); return false;}"></td> 
      </tr> 
    </table> 
  </form> 
<?=(!empty($csv->error) ? "<hr/>Errors: ".$csv->error : "")?> 
</body> 
</html>
```