# How to delete first 11 lines in a file using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, file-get-contents, php-7, file-handling

I have a CSV file in which I want the first 11 lines to be removed. The file looks something like:

```
"MacroTrends Data Download"
"GOOGL - Historical Price and Volume Data"
"Historical prices are adjusted for both splits and dividends"

"Disclaimer and Terms of Use: Historical stock data is provided 'as is' and solely for informational purposes, not for trading purposes or advice."
"MacroTrends LLC expressly disclaims the accuracy, adequacy, or completeness of any data and shall not be liable for any errors, omissions or other defects in, "
"delays or interruptions in such data, or for any actions taken in reliance thereon.  Neither MacroTrends LLC nor any of our information providers will be liable"
"for any damages relating to your use of the data provided."


date,open,high,low,close,volume
2004-08-19,50.1598,52.1911,48.1286,50.3228,44659000
2004-08-20,50.6614,54.7089,50.4056,54.3227,22834300
2004-08-23,55.5515,56.9157,54.6938,54.8694,18256100
2004-08-24,55.7922,55.9728,51.9454,52.5974,15247300
2004-08-25,52.5422,54.1672,52.1008,53.1641,9188600
```

I want only the stocks data and not anything else. So I wish to remove the first 11 lines. Also, there will be several text files for different tickers. So `str_replace` doesn't seem to be a viable option. The function I've been using to get CSV file and putting the required contents to a text file is

```
 function getCSVFile($url, $outputFile)
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($url);
        $content = str_replace("date,open,high,low,close,volume", "", $content);
        $content = trim($content);
        file_put_contents($outputFile, $content);
    }
```

I want a general solution which can remove the first 11 lines from the CSV file and put the remaining contents to a text file. How do I do this?

Comment: `file_put_contents(implode('', array_slice(file($url), 12)));`

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy The string in the first 11 lines will change depending on the text files. So I don't think it is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [skip first line of fgetcsv method in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372730/skip-first-line-of-fgetcsv-method-in-php)

Comment: ^ .. but just extend one of those methods to 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every example here won't work for large/huge files. People don't care about the memory nowadays. You, as a great programmer, want your code to be efficient with low memory footprint.

Instead parse file line by line:

```
function saveStrippedCsvFile($inputFile, $outputFile, $lineCountToRemove)
{
    $inputHandle = fopen($inputFile, 'r');
    $outputHandle = fopen($outputFile, 'w');

    // make sure you handle errors as well
    // files may be unreadable, unwritable etc…

    $counter = 0;
    while (!feof($inputHandle)) {
        if ($counter < $lineCountToRemove) {
            fgets($inputHandle);
            ++$counter;
            continue;
        }

        fwrite($outputHandle, fgets($inputHandle) . PHP_EOL);
    }

    fclose($inputHandle);
    fclose($outputHandle);
}
```

Comment: Isn't an fgets call missing in the if block ?

Comment: No. The `fwrite` will start working when a specific counter value is reached. Before that each `while` iteration will be skipped. [Proof of concept](https://3v4l.org/mjo9K)

Comment: But, unless I didn't understood the question, without the line `fgets($inputHandle);` before the continue, the function will not skip the firsts lines of the input file. The script will only increase the variable value without moving the file pointer.

Comment: Lol you're right. I totally missed that. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a CSV file in which I want the first 11 lines to be removed.

I always prefer to use `explode` to do that.

```
$string = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode('\n', $string);
for($i = 0; $i < 11; $i++) { //First key = 0 - 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 = 11 lines
    unset($lines[$i]);
}
```

This will remove it and with `implode` you can create a new 'file' out of it

```
$new = implode('\n',$lines);
```

`$new` will contain the new file

*Did'nt test it, but I'm pretty sure that this will work*

**Be carefull!** I will quote @emix his comment.

> This will fail spectacularly if the file content exceeds available PHP memory.

Be sure that the file isn't to 'huge'

Comment: That will remove 12 lines. You wanna write `$i < 11` instead of `$i <= 11`.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Was a typo :)

Comment: This will fail spectacularly if the file content exceeds available PHP memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file()` to read it as array and simply trim first 11 lines:

```
$content = file($url);

$newContent = array_slice($content, 12);

file_put_contents($outputFile, implode(PHP_EOL, $newContent));
```

But answer these questions:

1. Why there is additional content in this CSV?
2. How will you know how much lines to cut off? What if it's more than 11 lines to cut?

Comment: I downloaded the stocks data from Macrotrends. All the file contains some extra information about Macrotrends in the first 11 lines. After that, it is just the stocks data which I want.

Comment: This will fail spectacularly if the file content exceeds available PHP memory.