# How can i split the csv file so that i can make 2 tables from it?

Tags: php, csv

I need to make 2 tables from this csv file. How can i split the file, after the second line,

This is how the csv file looks.

> i've marked what i need as **headers**. i dont need the data from those
>   lines.

**Palle_nr;Varenummer;Ordre_nr;Operatoer;Maskin_nr**

1234;1234_2019_01_14_17_11_23;1234; TN;1234

;;;;

**Name;Datum;Property;Criterion;Type**

1) Height 130;;avg(L)Y;;inspection_dimension_scalar

And this is how my code looks. again what i want this code to do is split the csv file after the second line. so i get a table with the Palle_nr
and a table with the Name

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){

copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");

$row = 1;
if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $csvuser->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
    while ($getpdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
        $getpdata = array_map("utf8_encode", $getpdata);
        $totalp = count($getpdata);

        $row++;

        for ($i=0; $i < $totalp; $i++) {
            $pdata = implode(";", $getpdata);
            $palledata = explode(";", $pdata);
        }
        $csvuser->insertPalleTable($latest_filename,$palledata);
        }

///////// This is where i want the file to split ///////

     $header = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";");
     $header = array_map("utf8_encode", $header);
     $totalheader = count($header);
     for ($i=0; $i < $totalheader; $i++) {
         $headerdata = implode(";", $header);
         $th = explode(";", $headerdata);
         }

   $csvuser->createCsvTable($latest_filename);
   while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
   $getdata = array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata);
   $total = count($getdata);

   $row++;

   for ($c=0; $c < $total; $c++) {
        $csvdata = implode(";", $getdata);
        $fncsvdata = explode(";", $csvdata);
    }
     $csvuser->insertCsvTable($latest_filename,$fncsvdata);
    }
  }
}
```

If you need the whole code so you can recreate the problem. then ill upload it but thought it would be to much code.

Other ways of reading the file is also appreciated. i just need to be able to split the file.

Comment: A possible solution you can find here in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372730/skip-first-line-of-fgetcsv-method-in-php

Comment: The problem with that one is that i dont just need to skip the header. i need to create 2 tables from my csv file.

Comment: Do you have a variable number of lines of data under each header?

Comment: not under the first but under the second yes.

Comment: I think it will work if i can stop reading the file after the second line. and start reading it again for the rest of the data. but dunno how to do that.

Comment: The table creation part if it does work, its just the splitting of the file that is the problem

Comment: That implode-explode loop makes no sense to me

Comment: dunno exacly how it works but it gets the data that i need. that part aint made by me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so much that I have to question in your code, but because your first four lines in the file are predictable, you can consume them without looping.

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){
    copy("$sourcepath/$latest_filename","$copy/$latest_filename");

    if (($openfile = fopen("$copy/$latest_filename", "r")) !== false) {

        $header1 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        $csvuser->createPalleTable($latest_filename);
        $csvuser->insertPalleTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")));

        $delimiting_row = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use 

        $header2 = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";"); // consume, but don't use

        $csvuser->createCsvTable($latest_filename);
        while ($getdata = fgetcsv($openfile, 1000, ";")) {
            $csvuser->insertCsvTable($latest_filename, array_map("utf8_encode", $getdata));
        }
    }
}
```

This is completely untested (and posted from my phone).

Comment: Can you tell my why this works? tried to echo out the variables, and the $header2 doesnt show anything. i think its the empty row. can you confirm? :) Thanks again!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php returns an array, so `echo` won't do the trick.  You can implode with a glue to echo, or you can use `var_export()` or `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to output the array data.  When `fgetcsv()` is called, it extracts a single row/line, and advances the "pointer".  Making these calls manually (outside of a loop) give you the ability to step through the known rows until you get to the 2nd section of data that has variable lines of data.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! :)